# NSPointerArray weird compaction

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nspointerarray

I have a weak `NSPointerArray` with some `NSObject` that has been released. Before calling `compact` what I see is:

```
(lldb) po [currentArray count]
1
(lldb) po [currentArray pointerAtIndex:0]
<nil>
(lldb) po [currentArray allObjects]
<__NSArrayM 0x16f04f00>(

)
```

That makes sense, but what is really weird is that when I call `compact` on that array I see the same values! Count still returns 1 and `pointerAtIndex:0` is `nil`.

Why the nil hasn't been removed?

**EDIT**

Here's the full code (yeah it's XCTesting framework):

```
- (void)testCompaction {
    __weak id testingPointer = nil;

    NSPointerArray *weakArray = [NSPointerArray weakObjectsPointerArray];

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSObject *someObj = [[NSObject alloc] init];

        testingPointer = someObj;

        [weakArray addPointer:(__bridge void*)testingPointer];

        NSLog(@"before compaction inside autorelease: testingPointer = %@ count = %d, allObjects = %@, pointerAtIndex:0 = %@, pointerAtIndex:0 class = %@", testingPointer, [weakArray count], [weakArray allObjects], [weakArray pointerAtIndex:0], [(id)[weakArray pointerAtIndex:0] class]);

        someObj = nil;
    }

    NSLog(@"before compaction outside autorelease: testingPointer = %@ count = %d, allObjects = %@, pointerAtIndex:0 = %@, pointerAtIndex:0 class = %@", testingPointer, [weakArray count], [weakArray allObjects], [weakArray pointerAtIndex:0], [(id)[weakArray pointerAtIndex:0] class]);

    [weakArray compact];

    NSLog(@"after compaction outside autorelease: testingPointer = %@ count = %d, allObjects = %@, pointerAtIndex:0 = %@, pointerAtIndex:0 class = %@", testingPointer, [weakArray count], [weakArray allObjects], [weakArray pointerAtIndex:0], [(id)[weakArray pointerAtIndex:0] class]);
}
```

and logs:

```
  before compaction inside autorelease: testingPointer = <NSObject: 0x7de7ff80> count = 1, allObjects = (
    "<NSObject: 0x7de7ff80>"
), pointerAtIndex:0 = <NSObject: 0x7de7ff80>, pointerAtIndex:0 class = NSObject
2015-07-20 14:27:14.062 AppetizeSuite copy[54144:9019054] before compaction outside autorelease: testingPointer = (null) count = 1, allObjects = (
), pointerAtIndex:0 = (null), pointerAtIndex:0 class = (null)
2015-07-20 14:27:22.615 AppetizeSuite copy[54144:9019054] after compaction outside autorelease: testingPointer = (null) count = 1, allObjects = (
), pointerAtIndex:0 = (null), pointerAtIndex:0 class = (null)
```

Why the `compact` method does not delete the first pointer? It's clearly a `nil` before calling `compact`.

Comment: How did you add `some NSObject that has been released` to the pointer array? And are you using weakObjectsPointerArray?

Comment: @KazukiSakamoto could you please take a look at my updated question above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this same behavior. Here is an open radar bug report:
http://www.openradar.me/15396578

Answer (score 23):

The reason this happens is that `-compact` first checks whether an internal flag 'needsCompaction' is set. If it's not, it simply bails early. The only time the flag is set is if a nil pointer is inserted directly into the array through the public interface. It does not get set if a weakly referenced object is deallocated (and the pointer is nil'd) after the pointer was inserted into the array.

One work around for this behavior is to purposefully append a nil pointer to the array before calling `-compact`. Not ideal but it'll work.

```
[pa addPointer:nil]; // forces the pointer array to do compaction next time
[pa compact];
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It was very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's already a few year and using the sample code shows no change.

However, -compact is perfectly working when the update of the pointer is performed using the method -replacePointerAtIndex:withPointer:

In the code above, replacing

```
someObj = nil;
```

by

```
 [weakArray replacePointerAtIndex:0 withPointer:nil];
```

provides the expected result after `[weakArray compact];` and the code will crash at the last NSLog